# Execute two insert query codeigniter 2

Tags: mysql, activerecord, codeigniter-2

When i try to execute two insert query , the first works and the second doesn't ,

This is my code :

```
      foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
          $this->db->insert('db_purchased', $value);


      }

     // $data contains multiple arrays  $data =array(array(...))
```

How can i fix that ?

Comment: paste a `var_dump` of `$data`

Comment: Yes lets see $data, and why $data, that is CI internal variable?

Comment: [SOLVED] ... it was just a database table problem  ( missing table field)

THANKS FOR YOUR REPLAY